# how do i use a for loop to compare arrays of different sizes

Tags: c++

I have 2 arrays:

arr1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr2 = [0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6]

I'm trying to write a function to compare the two arrays and make a new array with the missing numbers.

I tried this for loop but it didn't print out anything. What other ways can I compare 2 arrays of different sizes?

```
int n = 0;
int *newArr = new int[];
for (int i = 0; i<=6; i++) {
 if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
 newArr[n] = arr1[i]
 n++;
}
}
for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
 cout << arr[j] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Get the size of both arrays, loop to the minimum one.

Comment: Are you sure you want to allocate array of 0 elements?

Comment: It would help if you would show what the content of `newArr` is supposed to look like after the looping is finished.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to write a function to compare the two arrays and make a
>   new array with the missing numbers.

You can use a range-based for loop and `std::find` to check both arrays for the missing numbers
And then store the result in a `std::set`

Example

```
int main()
{
  int           a[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  int           b[] { 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6    };
  std::set<int> c;

  for (auto const& i : a)
    if (std::find(std::begin(b), std::end(b), i) == std::end(b))
      c.insert(i);

  for (auto const& i : b)
    if (std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), i) == std::end(a))
      c.insert(i);
}
```

or using a regular for loop

```
for (auto it = std::begin(a); it != std::end(a); ++it)
  if (std::find(std::begin(b), std::end(b), *it) == std::end(b))
    c.insert(*it);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int arr1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int size_arr1 = 7;

int arr2[] = {0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6};
int size_arr2 = 6;

int *newArr = new int[size_arr1 + size_arr2];
int n = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size_arr1; i++) {
    newArr[n++] = arr1[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < size_arr2; i++) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (arr2[i] == newArr2[j]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        newArr[n++] = arr1[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << newArr[i] << endl;
}

delete[] newArr;
```

Another way to collect unique numbers from both arrays is to use a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::unsorted_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead, eg:

```
#include <unordered_set>

int arr1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int arr2[] = {0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6};
set::unsorted_set newArr;

for(int num : arr1) {
    newArr.insert(num);
}

for(int num : arr2) {
    newArr.insert(num);
}

for (int num : newArr) {
   std:: cout << num << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the arrays dynamically in your code (i.e. on the heap) and initializing them with numbers isn't as straight forward. You are also allocating an array of 0 size. If you declare your arrays on the stack then you can achieve what you want to do with a nested for loop.

Take note though that for large datasets this would be inefficient. If you're curious research binary search algorithms.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr1Size = 6;
    int arr2Size = 8;

    int arr1[] = { 2, 5, 7, 12, 45, 65 };
    int arr2[] = { 2, 5, 6, 10, 32, 65, 98, 123 };


    for (int i = 0; i < arr1Size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2Size; j++)
        {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
            {
                std::cout << arr1[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```